# I am getting the following error when forwarding port

Tags: amazon-web-services

kubectl port-forward deployment/sample-deployment 3500:80

Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3500 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:3500 -> 80
Handling connection for 3500
Handling connection for 3500`enter code here`
E0818 15:40:59.528834   22888 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 3500 -> 80: error forwarding port 80 to pod b2890d623a5c02aed2b49fca3d187d53ee768d897ab37d21d4dca19811f61ef6, uid : exit status 1: 2022/08/18 10:10:58 socat[23238] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:80, 16): Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that there is nothing listing on port 80 for that connector so the connection is being rejected. The port number after the colon needs to be a port that the service inside the container is listing on.